# in windows console is there a way to list all remembered commands that are in the buffer?

Tags: windows, console, cmd

I know that I can use up and down arrows to iterate trough these but is there a way to list them all at once ? That is all commands that system remembered during my session ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is..

If you are talking about cmd.exe

if so then open a command prompt and type in some commans ie dir, cls, dir, cls and then type in the following

```
doskey /history
```

This will display it on screen.

```
doskey /history>"c:\cmdHistory.txt"
```

That will run it with out display and out it to a file called cmdHistory.txt

```
doskey /history>"c:\cmdHistory.txt" && notepad.exe "c:\cmdHistory.txt"
```

That will run it with out display and out it to a file called cmdHistory.txt and then open the file.

***NOTE :*** !!!! You might need to run the cmd as administrator to be able to access you C:\ depending on which system you are using

Answer (score 2):

use doskey for that

```
doskey /history
```

(for more info, see `doskey /?`)